# How to write unit tests for text parser?

Tags: python, unit-testing, parsing

For background, I am somewhat of a self-taught Python developer with only some formal training with a few CS courses in school.

In my job right now, I am working on a Python program that will automatically parse information from a very large text file (thousands of lines) that's a output result of a simulation software. I would like to be doing test driven development (TDD) but I am having a hard time understanding how to write proper unit tests.

My trouble is, the output of some of my functions (units) are massive data structures that are parsed versions of the text file. I could go through and create those outputs manually and then test but it would take a lot of time. The whole point of a parser is to save time and create structured outputs. Only testing I've been doing so far is trial and error manually which is also cumbersome.

So my question is, are there more intuitive ways to create tests for parsers?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Your parser sounds like it should be broken down into smaller, easier-to-test parsers. For example, a parser for a simple range like `23-96` can be decomposed into two simpler parsers, one that recognizes numbers and another that recognizes `-`. Those are then *composed* into the range parser. (Note there's a close correlation between the sub parsers and the rules of the grammar you are parsing.) Now you can test the two subparsers individually, and then just test that your range parser simply uses the sub parsers correctly.

Comment: See the unit tests that are written for the pyparsing (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) module. Each one has an input and expected parsed output.

Answer (score 2):

Usually parsers are tested using a regression testing system. You create sample input sets and verify that the output is correct. Then you put the input and output in libraries. Each time you modify the code, you run the regression test system over the library to see if anything changes.

Comment: This is already very helpful. Just to clarify, so I would essentially still have to rely on manually verifying the output at least once before I can incorporate it as a part of a test? By libraries, do you mean a part of the test module?

Comment: Yes, usually commercial regression testing software maintains libraries of tests.